# YOUTUBE API search function doesnt work properly

Tags: php, youtube-api

I have a search function on my webpage where uses the youtube api to make a search for music videos. later on you can watch it on the same page. 
however when I use the api, and when I make a search for something with spaces in it the search function would work at all. when I make some changes to the string and replace all the spaces with "/", for example eminem lose yourself becomes: eminem/lose/yourself, and when yoy search for this you dont get the correct results. this is the peace of code I am using :
 this is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
<p>Search:
<input type="text" name="q" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" style="margin-top:-30px"/>
</p>
</form>
```

and then on my php side I have:

```
if (!isset($_POST['q']) || empty($_POST['q'])) {
        die ('ERROR: Please enter one or more search keywords');
} 
else {  
        $q = $_POST['q'];
    $q = str_replace(' ','/',$q);
        //echo $q;
```

}
      $feedURL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/{$q}?orderby=viewCount&max-results={$i}";
      $sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
      // get summary counts from opensearch: namespace
      $counts = $sxml-> children('http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/');
      $total = $counts->totalResults;
      $startOffset = $counts->startIndex; 
      $endOffset = ($startOffset-1) + $counts->itemsPerPage;

I tried different approaches to make the search function work. I used this $q = ereg_replace('[[:space:]]+', '/', trim($q)), which didnt work and then I started to replace the strings with "+", which didnt work properly again. 
I would like to see how can  I have a search function that works fine with spaces.

Comment: Have your tried to apply a `urlencode` to `$q` like you _should_ ? Spaces are not usually allowed in URLs, they should be encoded as `%20`. Slashes are allowed of course.

Comment: Also, it's very presumptuous to assume that a library - used by millions - _"doesn't work"_, you should always assume you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I did use urlencode but it doesnt work .

Answer (score 0):

Try to format your Query like this

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?
q=football+-soccer
&orderby=published
&start-index=11
&max-results=10
&v=2
```

Version of API is very important  v=2 is the latest stable version